# Is it safe and reliable to backup MySQL databases by backing up the data folder?

Tags: mysql, backup

I have a MySQL database [server version 5.0.x, type InnoDB] which I want to backup. I don't have username/password to back it up using `mysqldump`. My question, is it safe to back up the database by backing up the entire MySQL's `data` folder (of course, after stopping the MySQL server service in Windows 7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71417/34007).

In a word, a resounding "yes" is the answer to your question **provided** the server is stopped!

I'm not sure that there are any hot backups available for Windows - Percona's XtraBackup only works on Unix (AFAIK). It's possible that MySQL have a Windows solution for hot backups, but there's nothing Open Source - (again AFAIK, and it's been a while since I've looked at this issue).

But, you **are** perfectly **safe** with a cold backup!

I'm just wondering how you're planning to make use of the cold backup in the absence of a password? Does the app that uses it have it's own table dumping facility? My advice on this is to figure out how to get your raw data back ASAP!

Comment: The 3rd party application taking use of the database has the MySQL root password hard coded into its source I believe. It is a virtual machine running only that software and has one MySQL data database, the application's database.

Comment: But surely the data is yours? You should request a password which allows you to run mysqldump on a reasonably regular basis - the app code belongs to the 3rd party vendor, but the data belongs to you/your company! If they're not reasonable about this, I'd seriously consider changing vendor - for me it's imperative that I have access to **my** data anytime I require it - I'm not against 3rd parties retaining trade secrets in their own code, but **not** the data!